# Which feature class(es) is/are used by service?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-server

I have several feature classes and a lot of services. When I try to make my feature class versioned I get the message that the feature class is locked which is obvious.
But it's not telling me by which service it's locked.

Is there a possibility to work through all feature classes with ArcPy and find out in which service it's referenced?

Answer (score 7):

**ArcGIS Server 10.1+:**

You can do this, however there is no out-of-the-box functionality for this. The information about what feature classes are used (and from what database files they are coming) is not exposed via ArcGIS Server Manager / Services Directory / REST Admin.

However, this information is stored as service metadata within `C:\arcgisserver\directories\arcgissystem\arcgisinput\ServicePaths.MapServer\extracted` folder in `manifest.xml` file (there are both .json and .xml). .Xml file contains more detailed information, I recommend parsing this file (but you could start with .json first to get the idea).

Two tags you should look at in .xml file are `<Name>ServicePaths</Name>` - service name and multiple `<OnPremisePath>C:\GIS\Temp\test.gdb\StopsSandiego</OnPremisePath>` tags which will contain feature classes names and their catalog/geodatabase path.

Code wise, you could use Python to parse this .xml file, get a dictionary with this structure:

```
{str:(tuple)} #data type

{servicename:(featureclasspath)} #pseudocode
{servicename:(fc1,fc2,fc3); servicename1:(fc1,fc2); servicename2:(fc5);...} #pseudocode
```

When you are done with that, you can write a function that will return the key of the dictionary (servicename) based on the value (feature class path name you supply). This will let you know what services you should stop to release the lock to the feature class.

**UPDATE April 2016:** you can do this with the REST API [service manifest](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcgis-rest-api/index.html#/Service_Manifest/02r3000001vt000000/) for the service, added in ArcGIS Server 10.1 SP1:

```
http://localhost:6080/arcgis/admin/services/Parks/Landmarks.MapServer/iteminfo/manifest/manifest.%format%
```

where `%format%` is either `json` or `xml`

A post with full answer is here: [Python script to print the feature classes which are referencing AGS map services](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/190795/14435)

**ArcGIS Server 10.0:**

Go to `C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Server10.0\server\user\cfg` and open the .cfg file associated with your service. Look for the `<FilePath>` tag. Now you can iterate through all .cfg files in this folder with Python and get information on what .mxd files are used and since you have access to the .mxd you can get each [layer data source](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Layer_properties/000v0000002t000000/) path and thus feature class names.

```
<ServerObjectConfiguration>

    <Description></Description>

    <Properties>
        <FilePath>D:\temp\TempService.mxd</FilePath>
```

Comment: Alex, thanxs for the answer. I understand it but it looks to me that you're answer is related to version 10.1. I'm working with 10.0 (;-() and can't find that directory structure exactly and the xml file. Any hints? Thnxs!!

Comment: Ah I see. I've modified my answer to meet your needs.

Comment: Alex, thanxs again for your answer. It's clear to my now and can advance with my "search".

Answer (score 1):

The lock file should contains the server name and process `ID` (`PID`) like
`MyFeatureClass.MyServerName.57784.63616.sr.lock`.

The second number in the file name 63616 is the `PID`. If you have access to the server, got to the task manager under the Detail tab, search for that `PID`, and under the Command Line column you can identify the service name