# Python script to print the feature classes which are referencing AGS map services

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-server

I have an AGS site and need to identify which feature classes in my SQL Server DB reference the AGS map and feature services.  I am not familiar with this environment and would like to automate the process instead of digging around for what references what. Is it possible to use the ArcGIS REST API with Python to get each feature class that is being used by a map or feature service?

I am using ArcGIS Server 10.0.

Answer (score 6):

I have answered the same question here [Which feature class(es) is/are used by service?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/101816/which-feature-classes-is-are-used-by-a-service).

By the way, you can access this information manually in the ArcGIS Desktop application by right-clicking the service in the Catalog window and choosing Service Workspaces.

You can either read the service metadata:

> This information is stored as service metadata within
>   `C:\arcgisserver\directories\arcgissystem\arcgisinput\Landmarks.MapServer\extracted`
>   folder in manifest.xml file (there are both .json and .xml). .Xml file
>   contains more detailed information, I recommend parsing this file (but
>   you could start with .json first to get the idea).

You can access the REST Admin API to get this information by accessing the [service manifest](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcgis-rest-api/index.html#/Service_Manifest/02r3000001vt000000/):

```
http://localhost:6080/arcgis/admin/services/Parks/Landmarks.MapServer/iteminfo/manifest/manifest.%format%
```

where `%format%` is either `json` or `xml`

Here is a snippet from the result:

```
{'databases': [{'byReference': 'false',
                'datasets': [{'onServerName': 'Buildings'},
                             {'onServerName': 'Cemetries'},
                             {'onServerName': 'Churches'}],
                'onPremiseConnectionString': 'DATABASE=C:\\GIS\\InData\\Landmarks.gdb',
                'onPremisePath': '',
                'onServerConnectionString': 'DATABASE=C:\\arcgisserver\\directories\\arcgissystem\\arcgisinput\\Parks\\Landmarks.MapServer\\extracted\\v101\\landmarks.gdb',
                'onServerName': 'landmarks.gdb',
                'onServerWorkspaceFactoryProgID': 'esriDataSourcesGDB.FileGDBWorkspaceFactory.1'}],
 'resources': [{'clientName': 'devmachine',
                'onPremisePath': 'c:\\GIS\\InData\\Landmarks.mxd',
                'serverPath': 'C:\\arcgisserver\\directories\\arcgissystem\\arcgisinput\\Parks\\Landmarks.MapServer\\extracted\\v101\\Landmarks.msd'}]}
```

You can handle the tokens etc manually by building requests and parsing the results (as in [here](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Scripting_languages_and_the_ArcGIS_REST_API/0154000005w0000000/)) or by using a package for this, such as [restapi](https://github.com/Bolton-and-Menk-GIS/restapi) or [ArcREST](https://github.com/Esri/ArcREST/). Both are great and easy to get started. Post a separate question if you will problems writing a script.

Comment: I should have mentioned that I am using ArcGIS Server 10.0.  It appears as if the service manifest was introduced in 10.1.1

Comment: Oh, then see my other answer for 10.0 here http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/101816/which-feature-classes-is-are-used-by-a-service