# Get the list of map services where table "xyz" is used

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, feature-class, map-service, arcgis-10.6, feature-service

I have an SDE feature class:

[image: AS in Image]

And I'm looking to find, to how many map services it is pointing.

There are like duplicate map services pointing to same table, so I was trying to figure out how many duplicate services we have.

Is there any script/method to start with?

Comment: Feature classes don't ever point at map layers.  Map layers point at feature classes. You'd need to compile the sources of every map service layer, and look for duplicates (a dictionary could help).  If you had the MXDs from which the services were published, you'd probably have an easier time.

Comment: @Vince thanks for reply, I have more then 200 services in total and many servers. is there any way to verify by scripting.. i think by manually verifying every mxd source will consume time and for me its hard to get all MXD's

Comment: See [Identify which map services are locking feature class](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/194832/identify-which-map-services-are-locking-feature-class)

Comment: I'd certainly script the MXD content access, which wouldn't require admin access to the ArcGIS Servers; the compilation process would be the same; use data source path as a dictionary key to a list of services, adding new lists and appending to existing. Then you parse the dictionary keys and report all sources with multiple services.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i did it by following steps from here

https://developers.arcgis.com/rest/enterprise-administration/server/servicemanifest.htm

and verify datasets of every Mapserver